# How to add Cron to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I trying to develop a plugin to send emails to users in a **specific time**, so I have created my plugin like that :

```
add_action( 'my_hourly_event',  'sendEmail' );
public static function activate() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );
} // end activate

public static function deactivate() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
} // end activate

function sendEmail() { 
    wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message );
}
```

Then I add this to **wp-config.php** :

`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)`;

Finally I add my cron in my site :

`* /15 * * * wget -q -O - http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

But I didn't get anything, so please if someone has any idea I will be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

If you add :

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)
```

To `wp-config.php`, it's normal that your CRON is not gonna be executed; try removing this line or replacing it by :

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', false)
```